# Need to get is any child inside an element is having a background

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to find out is their any span having a style of background so I can get value from its attribute I have $(this). Structure is:

```
<div id="operative_time_limit" class="timedivd">
<span title="1 hours" data-y="1" data-x="0"></span>
<span title="2 hours" data-y="2" data-x="0"></span>
<span title="3 hours" data-y="3" data-x="0"></span>
<span title="4 hours" data-y="4" data-x="0"></span>
</div>
```

Using `alert(jQuery(this).children().css('background').length);` but always getting 0 as result

Comment: give  a class for elements having background color like `<span class="normal bagroundcolor" >`

Answer (score 0):

try this,

```
alert($('#operative_time_limit').find('span').length);
```

For `span` which has `background-color` property then try it like,

```
var c=0;
$('#operative_time_limit').find('span').each(function(){
     if($(this).css('backgroundColor')) // or 'background-color'
        c++;
});
alert(c);
```

Comment: but it will not return me span having color background

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what exactly `$(this)` is in your context.

However the following:

```
var count = 0;
$('#operative_time_limit span').each(function(index){
   if($(this).css('background')){
      count++;
   }
});
alert(count);
```

Will do it. Further extrapolating from your question to presume that you want to extract some attribute (lets call it `someAttr`), from the span with a background of css, and there is only one such span. Assuming those are correct assumptions, the following will give you what you want:

```
var attributeValue;
$('#operative_time_limit span').each(function(index){
   if($(this).css('background')){
      attributeValue = $(this).attr('someAttr');
   }
});
You now have your desired value in attributeValue
```

Comment: $(this) referrers to div having id operative_time_limit

Answer (score 0):

The following line will give you the length of Children of `$(this)`

```
alert(jQuery(this).children().css('background').length);
```

You could use the following code to find all the span's that have background color other than white (assuming white is default color)

```
var length = $('#operative_time_limit').children().filter(function () {
    return $(this).css('background-color') != 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)' && $(this).css('background-color') != 'transparent';
}).length;
```

here, variable `length` can be used to determine how many spans have background property

See working [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ehs8e/1/)

Answer (score -1):

use following

```
alert(jQuery(this).children().hasClass('background')).
```

hasClss determines whether any of the matched elements are assigned the given class.
The .hasClass() method will return true if the class is assigned to an element, even if other classes also are

Comment: i think this will check for class and not for style.